# QGIS new versions 3.28, 3.30... One part can not be selected, vertexes too, can't work with multi polygons, One part is "Hole lies outside shell"

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, geometry, vertices

I am currently stuck on working with polygons with QGIS versions from the new patches with the new styles (3.28, 3.30, maybe 3.26 too etc...)
When I used previous versions of QGIS, for instance 3.16 or similar- the issue is not present.

The issue: "Hole lies outside shell", after using "Fix geometries structure" and "check validity" with the new versions. (Experimented with v.clean, fix topology, check validity and other plugins and methods, they do not fix the issue).

Long story short, even if I use "fix geometries" linework / structure, when I am working with a multi polygon, 1 polygon with 2 separate parts - It does not allow me to select/hoover over one of the 2 parts of the feature, while trying to click select on the bugged one of the 2. It allows me once after using linework. Then it re-bugs.
Also the same for vertexes. I can't select/hoover over the vertexes of the second part of the polygon  > I can not work with half of the feature, as it is invalid geometry. And I do need the polygon to be on 1 feature on 2 or more separate parts.
I can see it after "check validity" is used > having invalid geometry - one of the parts is "Hole lies outside shell"
And I see visually the 2 parts of the feature, just one of them can not be selected or worked with.

Note 1. When I run the same shapefile in version 3.16 or similar (not 3.26-3.28-3.30) - I can "fix geometries" (where it is the old version, not split in 2 linework/structure). And afterwards I am able to select/select vertexes properly on both "parts" of the same feature of the polygon. And after "check validity" - there is no invalid geometry. Hence, I can work with such polygons in older QGIS versions.

Note 2. I also tried to work on both QGIS versions at the same time, to fix the geometry on one, and work on other, but it turns out that as soon as I even move 1 vertex or line from a polygon in the new version (after it is fixed in the old version) - it bugs again instantly, without using fix geometry, thus giving me invalid geometry.

Note 3. As the styles in the new QGIS versions are different from the old ones, I can not just work on this project on an older QGIS version, as I need to re-style. And I can not use any new QGIS versions, as the issue seems to be in all of them.

I tested with different input data of polygons, the issue does not seem to be coming from the data itself, but from the QGIS versions.

Comment: I cannot re-produce with QGIS 3.30. As a test I inserted a multipolygon as WKT into QuickWKT layer, applied Fix geometries -structure, and then edited the fixed layer (it is named "fixed" even there was nothing to fix) with Vertex tool.

Comment: Here is example shapefile: https://dox.abv.bg/download?id=cceb11a09e# -  The feature Sierra Leone . Currently it is bugged, 23 total invalid output, with 35 valid. Sierra Leone is an example for invalid one. This is tested on both 3.28 and 3.30.

Comment: Do you have have two QGIS versions installed on the same machine? Then it is possible that the new version is using some libraries from the older version and in that case all kind of oddities can happen.

Comment: I have 6 versions installed on the same machine, over the years I had more than 20. As I work with several at the same time, depending on their strong and weak sides.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded your shapefile. It does indeed have 23 faulty geometries with "hole lies outside shell". It probably means that some parts of multipolygons shells have wrong winding order so they are written as holes into the shapefile. I fixed the geometries with QGIS 3.30.3 by using the Fix geometries tool. Then I edited the fixed layer (the place is in the corner of the Sherbro Island) and saved the edits. Finally I run "Check validity" for the fixed and edited layer. No problem, all features are still valid.

[image]

It is possible to fix the geometries from a command line with ogrinfo. Notice that I did not select any attributes with SQL. Edit it as needed.

`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" fixed.shp stackexchange.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "select ST_MakeValid(geometry) from stackexchange"`

Now this command finds only valid geometries

`ogrinfo fixed.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select st_isvalidreason(geometry) from fixed"`

**EDIT**

Image that shows that Fix geometries - Structure works for me.
[image]

Details about my environment

[image]

Comment: Yes. I did that as well in QGIS lower versions, I myself cleared the issues with fix geometry in lower QGIS versions. But when I come back to the newer ones - again invalid geometry pops up.
But based on my actions, I can assume that if you send me now this file, and I try to use it in the new QGIS versions, again invalid geometry will pop up, hence my issue here.
Can you send it so I test it?

Comment: I have QGIS 3.30.3 on Windows, from OSGeo4W.

Comment: Alright. Can you send me this new, fixed file to test?

Comment: You can also check if the geometries are valid with ogrinfo `ogrinfo stackexchange.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select st_isvalidreason(geometry) from stackexchange"`. Check also what GDAL version you have with `gdalinfo --version`.

Comment: You can create a similar file with ogrinfo. I edited the answer to show how.

Comment: I wrote this in Python console, as well as in field calculator, but on both ends it gives me invalid syntax. 

ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" fixed.shp stackexchange.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "select ST_MakeValid(geometry) from stackexchange"

Comment: It should be run from a command window, and you must have the GDAL utility tools installed.

Comment: My apologies, as this will take way more time rather than the other test, can't we do the other one? Send me shapefile you fixed, and I will open it in 3.28 or 3.30.3 and see if I can work with that file.

Comment: Also, just noticed, that you did not reproduce my example. 
After you used fix geometries, you edited the fixed file.
The issue comes:
1. Fix geometries (linework, as structure bugs it instantly)
2. then save the changes
3. Then click on edit again
4. Then move a node (try 2 from both features)
5. Save the changes
6. Now check validity/ or just see if it is bugged with selecting features

Again, if I do this on older versions of QGIS, it works, but not on the new ones. It bugs after saving edits and trying again.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot reproduce your example with the QGIS 3.30.3 version that I have on my computer. As you can see from the image that I added, Fix geometries - structure just works for me. I tried the linework option as well but unfortunately it works perfectly as well. I do believe that your installation is broken.

Comment: Hey! I re-installed again 3.30.3 But the same issue remains. That after fix geometry (I will show you a picture, that indeed "Worked"), after I save the edits. But then edit the layer again and move some nodes around and save the edit, it re-bugs. Needs to be present several re-edits, for the bug to appear > then check valididity = 100% invalid geometry

https://prnt.sc/KwJ381tMKz03 - here is a picture with my environment compared to yours, everything matches except "Running against PROJ",
and fix geometry results,Project VER is different:
https://prnt.sc/9GmukzM6iFPT